# Nativescript UI templates

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

Are there any readily available UI templates that I can use for {N}+ Angular mobile app asides the nativescript-ui?

Comment: By template do u mean sample apps available ?

Comment: Check this out https://www.nativescriptthemebuilder.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can create basic angular application using

```
tns create myApp --ng
```

or

```
tns create myApp --template ng
```

Both options will take [this template](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tns-template-hello-world-ng) and will create basic Angular structure (master-detail like)

That said, you can now create your own template following [the structure of the one above](https://github.com/NativeScript/template-hello-world-ng) and re-use it for creating new projects with

```
tns create myApp --template <path-to-template>
```

Where the path can be local path, GitHub repository path or path to packed tgz.